# Creating/placing Mathematica cells anywhere

Tags: slideshows

I am interested in making powerpoint-like slides using Mathematica. The most appealing thing about writing documents in Mathematica is that it is so easy and quick to type complicated formulas with near Latex quality. If I were to type the same equations in powerpoint, the quality looks so bad and takes forever. The nice thing about powerpoint though is that you can virtually place text cells, graphic cells, etc, anywhere on the slide using the mouse, making it super easy to arrange things.

Is there away to do this in Mathematica, that is to rearrange cells anywhere I want by dragging the cells with my mouse? It appears that Mathematica only lets you arrange cells vertically. For example, you can't seem to create two separate text cells horizontally adjacent to each other.

Just to be clear, I'm asking for something different than creating a table/matrix in a single cell.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can make a cell in Slide mode and then cut and paste graphics into it, as such:

[image]

Go to `Drawing tools` palette in the Slide mode, then open `Operations` and then click on a new graphics box.  Then, just cut and paste your individual graphics elements (made in different cells) into that box; then drag and drop them wherever you wish.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, that is certainly what I am looking for!

Comment: I sincerely apologize. I am unable to as I have less than 15 reputation points. As soon as I get more, I will upvote your response.